# Unable to find chart for react.js

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, charts

[sample of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPUea.jpg)

This is my very first question here. How do i replicate this type of charts or graph? i want it to be dynamic, based on the input slider should move.I tried to search for the relevant charts in chart.js D3.js but couldn't find one, i thought that some or the other library must be providing with this type of chart. Even chatGPT wasn't of any help, and i need to submit it as a part of assignment i got for internship.

Kindly look in the sample provided above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.